# Instant gratification in B2B onboarding

Tags: web-app, user-research, onboarding, b2b

Instant gratification seems to work very well when onboarding B2C end-users. To the extent that it's pretty much table stakes in some app categories.

Intuitively it should translate into B2B SaaS, but I'm having a hard time finding supporting evidence (with the exception of a few blog posts). I'm curious about:

- What are the best-in-class examples for a B2B onboarding process which includes instant gratification elements?
- Alternatively, can anybody describe a B2B instant-gratification feature they launched, which resulted in a significant positive change?

Thanks!

Comment: welcome to the community @yoel - I like this question and hope to hear examples of positive change from an instant gratification feature.

Comment: thanks @albert ! looking forward to see how folks respond.

Answer (score 1):

We're facing this exact issue with our B2B customers with a new app release next week. We're releasing an MVP mPOS. Instant gratification, or more specifically dead simple functionality that can be easily reproduced (and is rewarding in that it does what the B2B customer needs), isn't difficult for this user type. In fact, it's infinitely easier because hey, if you're a SaaS, they already bought it!

Seriously though, our MVP started off with a 5-step tutorial for exactly this and we killed it because we knew that all customers would be idiots and that a tutorial wouldn't cut it. That's harsh...but the point is that typically the person buying your SaaS platform service are not the people using it day-to-day. Our salespeople sell their executive, and then our customer success/support people talk to their day-to-day employees. Two completely different groups of people, and the customer's knowledge of the product is effectively nill.

So like all B2B software, training is required. We built an mPOS, so now we're also building a demo video to show how it all works and how it all connects to the web-based platform. Until then, I (as the PM) field calls where I demo the app live, and am slowly training the team to handle customer queries.

All that said, the instant gratification isn't in the tutorial, it's in the product/service use. For us, it's making everything drop-dead simple. Meaning if the person handling the app drops dead, the next person who picks it up can continue at any step of the way and succeed. That's the motto, and that's what we've done. That makes the difference.

The tutorial, we've found after speaking with our customers and gauging everything from interest to understanding, doesn't matter. They rarely handle the product themselves and furthermore aren't technically savvy whatsoever. So the app is simple to appease to the actual users.

TL;DR - Don't worry about the tutorial, make everything else drop-dead simple and you'll be fine no matter what.

Comment: Thanks @Jamezrp! Super helpful example. Hope your launch went well, and looking forward to hearing you're afterthoughts!